Does a OP_CHECKSIGADD and OP_EQUAL script for a threshold signature fail if you provide too many valid signatures in the unlocking script?
For this CHECKSIGADD script for a 2-of-3 multisig:
<pk1> OP_CHECKSIG <pk2> OP_CHECKSIGADD <pk3> OP_CHECKSIGADD OP_2 OP_EQUAL

What happens if you provide more than the 2 required signatures, in this case 3 valid signatures for the 3 associated public keys? 3 is not equal to the required 2 so the OP_EQUAL would cause the unlocking script to fail? Would you need to use a greater than or equal opcode instead of OP_EQUAL if you are going to provide more valid signatures than required?

Yes, if you provide too many signatures, it will fail on the OP_EQUAL. Luckily, you can easily fix it by just dropping one of the signatures and replacing it with the empty byte vector instead.
You could permit additional signatures by replacing OP_2 OP_EQUAL with OP_1 OP_GREATER_THAN, or with OP_2 OP_GREATERTHANOREQUAL, however additional signatures would increase your input’s weight, so it seems preferable to just drop superfluous signatures.
